There are no $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and odd $k>1$ such that $\left(\dfrac{a}{k}\right)=1$ and $a^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod{k}$
Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $k>1$ be an odd number. Can it happen that $\left(\dfrac{a}{k}\right)=1$ and $a^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod{k}$, where $\left(\dfrac{a}{k}\right)$ is the Jacobi symbol (also Kronecker symbol)? I couldn't find any solution using a computer program.
Taking the Jacobi symbol $\left(\dfrac{\cdot}{k}\right)$ (which only depends on the remainder modulo $k$) yields
$$\left(\dfrac{-1}{k}\right)=\left(\dfrac{a}{k}\right)^{\frac{k-1}{2}}=1,$$
so $k\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. But I couldn't really say anything more than this. Thank you for any help/hint in advance.

Interesting question! https://oeis.org/A262051 , https://oeis.org/A262052 and https://oeis.org/A262054 are tables of composite $n$ for which $a^{(n-1)/2} \equiv \pm 1 \bmod n$, for $a=3$, $5$ and $7$. I went through them and computed the ordered pair $(a^{(n-1)/2} \bmod n, \left( \tfrac{a}{n} \right))$. Each of the combinations $(1,1)$, $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,-1)$ occurred often, but $(-1,1)$ never did.

Use \pmod{k} to get the space, parentheses, and  roman typeface "mod". Don't use that MathJax hack.

@ArturoMagidin Thanks for your suggestion, I just didn't like the large space after $\operatorname{mod}$ :)

@DavidESpeyer Yes, so glad that we have received an answer :)

There is no such $(a,k)$ pair! The OP's observation that $k$ has to be $1 \bmod 4$ was the right place to start. I will show that $k$ must be $1 \bmod 2^j$ for all $j$, and thus $k = 1$.
Let the prime factorization of $k$ be $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_r$.
Claim 1: Suppose that $k \equiv 1 \bmod 2^j$. Then each prime $p_i$ is $\equiv 1 \bmod 2^j$.
Proof: Since $k \equiv 1 \bmod 2^j$, we have $(k-1)/2 \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{j-1}$. So $-1$ is a $2^{j-1}$-th power modulo $a$. In particular, there is a primitive $2^j$-th root of unity modulo $p_i$ for each prime $p_i$ dividing $a$, and we deduce that $p_i \equiv 1 \bmod 2^j$. $\square$
Claim 2: Suppose that each prime $p_i$ is $\equiv 1 \bmod 2^j$.  Then $k \equiv 1 \bmod 2^{j+1}$.
Proof: Write $p_i = 1+2^j q_i$ and write $k = 1+2^j \ell$. Note that we have $\ell \equiv \sum q_i \bmod 2$, and our goal is to show that $\ell$ is even.
Put $b = a^{\ell}$, so $b^{2^{j-1}} = a^{2^{j-1} \ell} = a^{(k-1)/2} \equiv -1 \bmod k$. So $b$ is a primitive $2^j$-th root of unity modulo $p_i$ for each prime $p_i$. We therefore have $\left( \tfrac{b}{p_i} \right) = (-1)^{(p_i-1)/2^j} = (-1)^{q_i}$.
Then
$$\left( \tfrac{b}{k} \right) = \prod_i \left( \tfrac{b}{p_i} \right) = (-1)^{\sum q_i} = (-1)^{\ell}.$$
But, also $$\left( \tfrac{b}{k} \right) = \left( \tfrac{a}{k} \right)^{\ell} =1.$$
So $(-1)^{\ell} = 1$, and $\ell$ is even as desired. $\square$
Combining the two claims, we have $k \equiv 1 \bmod 2$ implies $p_i \equiv 1 \bmod 2$ implies $k \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ implies $p_i \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and so forth. So $k \equiv 1 \bmod 2^j$ for all $j$, and $k=1$. QED

That's very nice! Thanks a lot! :)
